# How to handle looping and runtime error program from php

Tags: php, c, loops, runtime, infinite

I want to create a web that can accept C code program, compile, and run the program on my server using php & gcc. But i can't handle infinite loop program, it's give me out of memory. And for runtime error program it's make my browser crash. What should i do to handle that problem? Many thanks.

Comment: Cool that you can write C code that hangs the (client side) browser when it is compiled on the server. You sure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a lightweight C code sandbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980170/how-to-create-a-lightweight-c-code-sandbox)

Comment: ... and creating a sandbox for C isn't easy. I'd advice against it.

Comment: I already wrote one, here's the code that sits on my page: `<a href="http://ideone.com/">Test your C Code</a>`.

Comment: Ehmm no, i still test it on my localhost...im not publish it yet

Answer (score 0):

What about programs that require user input? PHP would know nothing about that and things would freeze at the `shell_exec()` stage. Do you really want to open the door to allowing arbitrary C code to be run on your server?  This is pretty much the equivalent of putting a big sign on your house's front door saying "Come in, free house contents! Steal everything! Enjoy!".

Comment: Technically, it is possible to sandbox C applications sufficiently that it's safe to run them, but it requires some very careful system engineering. If your design doesn't even "handle infinite loop program", it doesn't stand a chance against intentionally malicious code.

Comment: Indeed. Even a simple chroot jail would help a ton, but then you still have to deal with `int main() { for (;;) {} }` junk.

Comment: And chroot jails only restrict filesystem access anyways. The "jailed" application still has full access to the network and to other processes running under its UID.

Comment: Hmmm...can i do some checking procedure before run that code on my server? Maybe check execution time or limit memory to use?

Comment: Jane: that's a fool's errand. Instead, you need to come up with an limited environment. Instead of figuring out what to blacklist, come up with your own libc and system libraries that explicitly whitelist what you'd like to do. Anything else will just get your system trashed. In other words: You're in for a long hard slog.