# How to compile c code on website

Tags: c, compilation, web

How can compile the code on a website. I am trying to make website where certain user can put there c code and compile it online.
I have seen a lot of posts but i am still not clear how to approach. I have windows server hosting.

Comment: Read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980170/how-to-create-a-lightweight-c-code-sandbox)

Comment: is there any pre built library which i can use to compile

Comment: There are many open-source solutions, you may google "open source online judge system" for more information. AFAIK, most of those were implemented under linux.[link]https://code.google.com/p/hustoj/ is one of the best OJ system I had ever tried, Unfortunately, it lacks of English documentation.